# MongoMemoryServer: Instance closed unexpectedly in supertest for express app

Tags: linux, mongodb, ts-jest, supertest, mongo-memory-server

I am trying to use Mongo Memory Server in supertest to test my API, but I get the following error:

```
    Starting the MongoMemoryServer Instance failed, enable debug log for more information. Error:
 UnexpectedCloseError: Instance closed unexpectedly with code "1" and signal "null"
    at MongoInstance.closeHandler (/home/jonathanpotter/code/express-apps/rest-api-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/util/MongoInstance.ts:543:52)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12)
```

My test is as follows:

```
import supertest from "supertest";
import createServer from "../utils/server";
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const app = createServer();

describe("product", () => {

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    await mongoose.connect(mongoServer.getUri());
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.disconnect();
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  });

  describe("get product", () => {
    describe("given the product does not exist", () => {
      it("should return a 404", async () => {
        const productId = "product123";
        await supertest(app).get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

My testing dependencies are:

```
"jest": "^29.3.1",
"mongodb-memory-server": "^8.10.2",
"supertest": "^6.3.3",
"ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
"ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
```

...and I my operating system is Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS.

edit: This all works fine on my Mac, but not on my Linux machine. Does anyone know of a fix for Linux (Pop!OS)?

Comment: I had a similar issue with it working fine on my Mac (no mongo install) but failing on a CircleCI build using their own image `cimg/node` but it worked fine when I switched to `node: bullseye` which is a Debian 11 release. So, it's definitely a host OS config or compatibility issue.